# index is out of bounds error when combining shapes in excel

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I am trying to create shape in excel and combine all shapes in a group. Below is a sample for just one line. I don't understand why the program is throwing Index is out of bounds error.

```
Public Sub Test()
        
            Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook
            Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
            sht = CType(wb.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

            Dim midobj() As Object
            Dim counter As Integer = 0
            Dim line1 As Excel.Shape = sht.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeLineCallout1, 100, 10, 110, 10)
            ReDim midobj(0)
            midobj(0) = New Object() {line1}

            MsgBox(midobj.GetUpperBound(0)) 'displays 0
            sht.Shapes.Range(midobj).Group() 'throws error

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure about _ReDim midobj(0)_?  Won't that be making midobj a zero-length array?  For that matter, why are you creating an array with one element?

Comment: This is just a sample , i would be adding multiple lines on a for loop and redim with preserve option

Answer (score 0):

`Worksheets("SheetName").Shapes.Range([arg])` is used to reference a subset of the shapes present on the named worksheet (i.e. objects in that sheet's Shapes collection). The argument of the `Shapes.Range` method can either be:

- An `Integer`, referring to the index of the shape in the Shapes collection
- A `String`, referring to the name of a shape in the Shapes collection.
- An `Array` containing strings and/or integers, referring to the names/indices of shapes in the `Shapes` collection.

So, the array should contain the shape name or its index.

Comment: The answer is partially correct, you are right that the array should contain a shape name. The main problem though is that excel cannot group an object beyond certain pixels.